# Laravel: Auth::check() from external ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Is it a way to check if user is authorized by ajax from external script (at same domain)? I know the way with `api_token`, but maybe this can be done easier, for example send cookie to Laravel website and somehow check if user with this cookie is authorized.

Comment: Just use the `AuthenticatedMiddleware` on your route. It will respond with an error if you're not logged in

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, thanks, but always get 'Unauthorized' error, but at the another browser tab I have authorized user.

Comment: That makes no sense. What method are you using for Authentication?